# win 8 store app bind to desktop tray

Tags: desktop, winjs, windows-store, tray

I try to create a win 8 store app by using winJs.
This app should have a desktop tray, which is not visible if used win RT.

Tray should be able to send and recieve data from the App.

It is possible?

I am going to use winforms tray  with wcf to connect app.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing a lot of stuff here.

When you create a Windows 8 app (as in Windows Store apps) you will not know if it's running on WinRT or full Windows.

Also, as of today, when Windows 10 is not out yet, Windows Store apps run in a separate view from old school windows (WinForms) apps.

So, I guess the answer to you question, if I understood correctly, is no, what you want is not possible (today)